# What is the right way for JavaScript functions to accept variables

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, scope

I'm new to JS and a bit confused on this subject, I hope you'll understand the question:

When I want to use in one function a variable coming from another,
or coming from an event such as `onClick` etc..
what would be the right way to move it from the HTML or another function into the executed function

working (well not yet..) example: i have a page with a few multi-choice questions, each question is a new form, i want to have one function for all the submit buttons, and when submitting to detect the name of the form, so should i use `onsubmit="validate(this)`? or is there a better way to take the form's name and put it to the `validate` function,

and also in general, when i use `function something(){}` and i want it to get variables from outside do i have to make `function something(a,b,c){}` or does it depends on the scope of the variable? hmm.. i'm not even sure i understand enough to formulate a good question, so any reference to an article or tutorial on this topic will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a few core function concepts to JavaScript that should be able to help. First and formost: for dealing with DOM events you will probably want to rely on a library, unless you literally have 0 browser compatibility expectations. I suggest looking into [jQUery](http://www.jquery.com).

That said, unobtrusive JavaScript (per @Raynos answer) is the right way to bind events in JavaScript and gives you a lot of flexibility. Take the following example:

```
function setup_events(){
  var my_form = document.form[0],
      form_name = my_form.name;
  my_form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    console.log( form_name ); // this is retained through the closure.
  });
}
```

You see you can bind data into event functions by using the concept of a closure, or the context of an outer scope after the outer scope has returned from within an inner scope. Now when you execute setup_events you will bind the `submit` event with a function who internally has access to the outer variable form_name. This can produce some nasty side effects if you do not understand function scope so look out for code like this:

```
// XXX : BAD CODE
function setup_events(){
  var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0], // assumes there is a <ul>
      count = 0;
  for ( var li in ul.childNodes ) {
    li.addEventListener('click', function( event ){
      alert( count ++ ); // this will always alert the count of list, not the list position
    }
  }
}
```

You can use [Immediately Invoked Function Expressions](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to create the necessary closures to retain the correct state. So to "fix" the above code you would use something like:

```
// XXX : BETTER CODE
/**
 * NOTE: NEVER CREATE FUNCTIONS INSIDE A LOOP
 * this example only shows the immediate solution to the above problem
 * with regard to function scope and closures.
 */
function setup_events(){
  var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0], // assumes there is a <ul>
      count = 0;
  for ( var li in ul.childNodes ) {
    li.addEventListener('click', (function( count ){
      return function ( event ){
        alert( count ); // this will alert the position in the list
      };
    })(count ++))
  }
}
```

Comment: backbone is awesome but it's not a DOM library, it's a code structure library. A good alternatives to jQuery would be ender. (A good alternative to backbone is spine). Also that second example has the _BIG_ problem of creating functions in loops. It's a very common example of lack of block scope but it's simply bad code.

Comment: @Raynos I agree that creating functions in a loop is bad code but didn't want to conjure up another example to use. I will note the badness of the code in the example.

Comment: we need a good example to conjure up for issues with block scope :) I havn't found one yet which is just a pitfall rather then bad code.

Comment: first, thank you for your really detailed answer, however i'm not sure i understood it all, mainly the last example, you say never create functions inside a loop, but the eventlistner is firing a function, what did i miss?

Comment: @IlyaD I was indicating that the pattern expressed is a bad one, unfortunately it is also one of the only ways to show the difference between block scope and function scope that makes any sense. The idea is that a function can return another function ( function is a data type ) and that inner function has access to the outer functions scope even after execution has finished. This is EXTREMELY powerful but can be dangerous if not understood.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend un obtrusive javascript.

```
document.form[0].addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    switch (event.target.name) {
        // switch form name.
    }
});
```

When you design a general function you should think of the arguments you want to accept.

For example

```
function addNumbers(one, two) {
    // add them
}
```

Is designed to take two numbers. You should use your functions as they are *designed* with the correct arguments.

```
<div id="bar"> 3 </div>

...

(function() {
    // local variables
    var one = 1;
    var two = 2;

    // Your getting number 3 globally from the HTML.
    var three = document.getElementById("bar").textContent;

    // passed in as parameters
    console.log(addNumbers(one, two)); // 3
    console.log(addNumbers(two, three)); // 5

})();
console.log(one) // undefined.
```

Comment: Ok, but say one and two are global, what will be the difference if i just use
`function addNumbers() {
    someUseForOne = one
}`

Comment: @llyaD we avoid global variables at all costs.

Comment: @Raynos OK, but if they come from outside the function they are already global, or am i mistaken?

Comment: @llyaD not if there passed in as parameters. If you mean global as in it's stored in the DOM then you can ask the DOM for the data.

Comment: @Raynos if you pass them as parameters then they are not global? i'm only beginning to get my grasp around the scope thing...
and i don't think i understand the second part, i surely didn't meant what you said.. :)

Comment: @llyaD you don't need global _javascript_ variables. All your global data is in the HTML document. See my further example.

Comment: @Raynos ok then, so how do i take parameters like the form name, the checked value, and how do i access them from within the function executed by the listener?

Comment: @llyaD the form name is `event.target.name`. The checked value is `document.getElementById("checkboxid").checked`

Comment: @Raynos can i get the value by the radio-button name? or is it better to give all 4 radio-buttons the same id and use what you wrote?

Comment: @llyaD you can get it by name or by CSS class name. Id's need to be unique though. You may want to look at a client side library like [ender](http://ender.no.de/). Which gives you some useful tools like `$([name='foobar'])`

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have a function like:

```
function something(){
...
}
```

You can still do something like this:

```
something(1,2,3);
```

The results would be in an associative object in the function so you can access them like this:

```
function something(){
    //check for args:
    if(arguments === undefined){...}
    arguments[0]; //which is 1 in our case
    //etc
}
```

But in reference to an `on{something}`, you usually have to pass `this`, or use some sort of event handler

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, not exactly, but you get the idea:

```
function onSubmitClick(){
    if(document.getElementById('choice1').checked==true){
        //store result
    }else if((document.getElementById('choice2').checked==true){
        //store result
    }else if(document.getElementById('choice3').checked==true){
        //store result
    }else if(document.getElementById('choice4').checked==true){
        //store result
    }else{
        //they didn't choose any
```